# import existing git into the gerrit

Tags: git, import, repository, gerrit

I was working on the project with git, and now I am trying to import it to the gerrit for better SCM.

I know I can import existing git repo by copying it into the gerrit or direct pushing without reviewing.

However, I want to preserve commit history into the gerrit.

For doing that, I tried pushing all the commits of the master branch into the gerrit.

git push  HEAD:refs/for/master

However, it was not pushed because it does not have a change-id.

I know I can attach change-id to the last commit, but it is useless if it is not attached in the first commit.

If I modify the first commit message by resetting to the first commit, I can push the first commit to the gerrit.

However, in this case, I still cannot preserve next commit history because change of the first commit makes conflicts with next commits.

Is there any good idea for solving this?

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to preserve it into the gerrit server so that all the history is shown in the All->merged of the gerrit server

...

> it was not pushed because it does not have a change-id.

If you really want to show all commits in the All->merged page, you are doing it right.  Be aware that once you work around the change-id issue you will have to mark each commit as reviewed and submit them individually.  If you have a large number of commits in your repository history, this will take quite a while.  You could look into automating it with an SSH or REST script.

To get past the change-id issue, there is a project setting to not require this tag.  Go to the admin page for your project (See [example](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/#/admin/projects/gerrit)) and look for the `Require Change-Id in commit message:` setting.  Change it to `False` and save your changes, then do your push.  You'll probably want to set it back to `True` or `Inherit` when you are done.

Answer (score 0):

with direct push you can preserve commit history as well. So instead of pushing to review branch push them to the remote branch directly. `git push origin master`
you need a [direct push](https://review.typo3.org/Documentation/access-control.html#category_push) and [forge commiter](https://review.typo3.org/Documentation/access-control.html#category_forge_committer) permission

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I already tried it and it is not solution I wanted. It pushes commits into the git repository without reviewing. I want to preserve it into the gerrit server so that all the history is shown in the All->merged of the gerrit server

Answer (score 0):

At the time of gerrit installation, please set the repository path as your existing git repository location.

I have also raised a similar doubt regarding this.
see [Gerrit - Gitlab Integration](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23216747/227775)